# Reading timeseries data into Octave data structure and iterating over it

Tags: time-series, octave

I want to implement a machine learning algorithm using Octave. I am new to Octave, and although I have read some of the online tutorials, it is still not clear to me how to do the following:

1. Read a CSV file into a suitable Octave struct. The data will be market data obtained from Google/Yahoo and saved as a CSV file. It will have the following columns (fields):
   Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume
2. Iterate over the data structure populated in step 1 above. I remember that in one of the Online Octave manuals, it mentioned that an array of structs is slower than a struct of arrays, but provided no example of how to create a struct of arrays.
3. Be able to select subsets of the data for specified times e.g. Date field >="01-Jan-2001" && <="01-Jan-2012". The extracted data should be in the same data type as in step 2 above (i.e. an iterable data type).

Can anyone help with some snippets that show how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For your problem #1 there's many tutorials out there already. Reading a CSV files is [unfortunately not as easy as it should be](http://abandonmatlab.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/matlab-cant-read-plain-text-data-out-of-a-wet-paper-bag/), apparently there's many things to take into account.

For your problem #3 see [recipe](http://wiki.octave.org/Cookbook#Retrieve_a_field_value_from_all_entries_in_a_struct_array) on Octave's cookbook. On the discussion section, I wrote a bit on the discussion about using it with logical indexing which seems appropriate for your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this statement: "... unfortunately as easy as it should be". Did you mean the opposite?. Also, could you please post links that show how to deal with 1 and 2?. Tx

Comment: Yes, I meant the opposite. I have fixed it and added a nice read. Octave is kinda stuck in reproducing Matlab behaviour most of the times. Try `csv2cell` to read the file, and then convert it into a struct with `cell2struct`.